# What is the correct way to do this?

Tags: java, arrays, scope

I know this must be a fundamental design problem because I clearly can't do this.  I want to call the ownGrokk, ownTyce, etc methods from another class depending on the value of the integer assigned to OwnedSpirits(int).  This in turn fills arrays.

The problem is, I do this multiple times, and doing it from another class it seems like I have to make a new object every time to pass the new int argument, and doing so resets the value of spiritInstance.  And, since that resets to zero, the arrays don't fill properly.  I try to print out my array values later and I get an "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException".

```
public class OwnedSpirits {       
    private int spiritTypeInt = 0;

    public static int spiritInstance=0;                                                  
    public static int[] spiritarray = new int[9];
    public static String[] spiritName = new String[9];
    public static int[] party = new int[3];

    public OwnedSpirits(int spiritcall){
        if(spiritcall == 1){
            ownGrokk();
        }     
        if(spiritcall == 2){
            ownRisp();
        }
        if(spiritcall == 3){
            ownTyce();
        }
        if(spiritcall == 4){
            ownDaem();
        }
        if(spiritcall == 5){
            ownCeleste();
        }
    }

    private void ownGrokk(){ 
        spiritName[spiritInstance] = "Grokk";
        spiritInstance++;                
    }

    private void ownRisp(){     
        spiritName[spiritInstance] = "Risp";
        spiritInstance++;              
    }

    private void ownDaem(){ 
        spiritName[spiritInstance] = "Daem";
        spiritInstance++;      
    }

    private void ownCeleste(){ 
        spiritName[spiritInstance] = "Celeste";
        spiritInstance++;          
    }

    private void ownTyce(){ 
        spiritName[spiritInstance] = "Tyce";
        spiritInstance++; 
    }
```

and this code is in another class, where it attempts to call the methods to fill the array

```
buttonConfirm.addListener(new ClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {                                
        if(xcounter==3){
            for(x=0; x<3; x++){
                if(setdaemtrue == true){
                    new OwnedSpirits(4);
                }
                if(setrisptrue == true){
                    new OwnedSpirits(2);
                }
                if(setcelestetrue == true){
                    new OwnedSpirits(5);
                }
                if(settycetrue == true){
                    new OwnedSpirits(3);
                }
                if(setgrokktrue == true){
                    new OwnedSpirits(1);
                }    
            }
        }
    }
});
```

and finally in yet another class:

```
System.arraycopy(OwnedSpirits.spiritName, 0, partylist, 0, 3);

@Override
public void show() {
    System.out.println(partylist[0]);
    System.out.println(partylist[1]);
    System.out.println(partylist[2]);

    spiritlist.setItems(partylist);
    table.add(spiritlist);
    table.setFillParent(true);
    stage.addActor(table);      
}
```

If the last part is confusing, it's because I am using libgdx.  the print statements are there just to try to figure out why my list was having an error

Comment: One thing you could do to make your overall design better would be to remove the copy-paste code.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I think you can solve your problem by making `spiritInstance` a static attribute. Your static arrays seem to be designed to track data about all instances of the `OwnedSpirits` class that have been constructed, so to properly index those arrays, you need a static counter that is incremented once for every construction. Why have you made `spiritInstance` an instance attribute?

Comment: zenith I have no idea what you mean

Comment: A strange aspect of your code is that your static arrays are of different lengths. If you're trying to allocate enough room in each static array to hold data on all possible instances that might be allocated, why would they be of different lengths? The `party` array is only 3 elements, while `spiritarray` and `spiritName` are 9. These should be uniform lengths, there should probably be an assertion in the constructor that you're not about to exceed that max, and when you print, you should make sure not to exceed the max (or the number of instances that have actually been allocated).

Comment: bgold it actually is static, I accidentally erased that it was static while trying to format the code onto this post.  I was having some problems formatting it.

Comment: the reasons for the varying lengths is that the ones that are 9 are actually going to be much larger than that.  i just put them at 9 right now for simplicity, I will make them bigger if I need to (and I will).  The array that is just 3 is for my active party in the game, which is 3 members.  The other arrays are like "reserves" that I can switch out into my party.  The length of these arrays shouldn't matter here.  Actually most of the code doesn't matter.  That must be what Zenith meant.  I'll edit it right now.

Comment: @TravisBlack I think you are having a wrong aproach with composition. Try making a Spirit class that contains the team, party, reserves, etc. The information related to the Spirit itself.
   To track information about spawned spirits, Try with a spawn(int spiritType) method, returning you a instance of Spirit. Using the constructor of OwnedSpirits, to advance and fill static public arrays seems weird. Could you expand more in what you are trying to achieve in the end?

Comment: Well I am making a game.  Not because I think I am a good enough programmer to make a good game, but more to learn how to make games.  I am using libgdx.  At this point I go through a "selection process" where you have a menu and pick 3 spirits out of 5 to make up your party.  After you pick them and confirm it you start the game.  Once you have started the game you can check your team.  I am trying to code in the ability to check your team, pulling the information out of an array - in this case the array for the 3 spirits that are in your current active party.

Comment: my mind has trouble comprehending how a large collection of spirits would be tracked through methods though.  Like If I have a "reserve section" of spirits, where I store 100 spirits I can call back for later, all with different stats and names (I want the player to be able to rename them)

Comment: I meant that there's much repetition in your code which could be easily eliminated (and probably should for the sake of good design). I made an [example](https://gist.github.com/emlai/9ac018f8acf4dbc1741f) to demonstrate it for you. Feel free to use that if it seems to fit to what you want to accomplish.

Comment: zenith I am pretty sure I just learned a lot from that code lol, thank you.  people have been repeatedly giving me advice of creating more objects but it's hard to wrap my head around *how* to use them for some things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can show you what I would do to handle Spirits, and Parties.
The Spirit class, contains name and current party its assigned to:

```
package com.stackoverflow.spirit;

public class Spirit {
    private String name;
    private Party party;
    private SpiritType type;
    private static int id = 0;

    public static enum SpiritType {
        Grokk, Risp, Tyce, Daem, Celeste
    };

    public Spirit(String name, SpiritType type) {
        create(name, type);
    }

    public Spirit(SpiritType type) {
        create(null, type);
    }

    // This is to handle Java inexistance of default parameter values.
    private void create(String name, SpiritType type)
    {
        Spirit.id++;

        this.name = (name == null) ? (type.name() + " " + id) : name;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Party getParty() {
        return party;
    }

    public SpiritType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    /**
     * Used internally by @see Party
     * @param party the party this Spirit belongs
     */
    public void setParty(Party party) {
        this.party = party;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Finally the Party class, contains a set of Spirits, you can add and remove Spirits from the party.

```
package com.stackoverflow.spirit;

import java.util.HashSet;

public class Party {
    private HashSet<Spirit> spirits = new HashSet<Spirit>();
    private static int id = 0;
    private String name = "Party " + Party.id++;;

    public Party() {
    }

    public Party(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void add(Spirit spirit) {
        if (!spirits.contains(spirit)) {
            spirits.add(spirit);

            if (spirit.getParty() != null) {
                //Remove from previous party to update the other party set
                spirit.getParty().remove(spirit);
            }
            spirit.setParty(this);
        } else {
            // throw new SpiritAlreadyOnParty();
        }
    }


    public void remove(Spirit spirit)
    {
        if (spirits.contains(spirit))
        {
            spirit.setParty(null); // You could create a default empty party for "Nature/Neutral" Spirits perhaps :)
            spirits.remove(spirit);
        }
        else {
            //throw new SpiritNotInParty();
        }
    }

    public boolean isOnParty(Spirit spirit) {
        return spirits.contains(spirit);
    }

    public ArrayList<Spirit> getSpirits()
    {
        return new ArrayList<Spirit>(spirits);
    }

    public int getPartySize() {
        return spirits.size();
    }

    public String getPartyInfo()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.append("Party:" + this.name + " Size:" + this.spirits.size() + "\n");
        for (Spirit s : spirits)
        {
            builder.append(s.getName() + "\n");
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }


    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Here I use the Spirit and Party classes, you could add more functionality, like properties for party strength, magic buffs on the party, etc:

```
package com.stackoverflow.spirit;

import com.stackoverflow.spirit.Spirit.SpiritType;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Party griffindor = new Party("Griffindor"), slytherin = new Party(
                "Slytherin");

        // You can also do for (SpiritType type : SpiritType.values() then
        // type.ordinal()
        for (int i = 0; i < SpiritType.values().length; i++) {
            griffindor.add(new Spirit(SpiritType.values()[i]));
            slytherin.add(new Spirit(SpiritType.values()[i]));
        }

        Spirit mySpirit = new Spirit("NotAHPFan", SpiritType.Celeste);

        slytherin.add(mySpirit);

        System.out.println("Name of party:" + mySpirit.getParty().getName());
        System.out.println("Is on griffindor?:"
                + griffindor.isOnParty(mySpirit));

        // What now?
        griffindor.add(mySpirit);
        System.out.println("Is " + mySpirit.getName() + " on "
                + slytherin.getName() + "?:" + slytherin.isOnParty(mySpirit));

        System.out.println(mySpirit.getName() + " is now on "
                + mySpirit.getParty() + "\n");


        System.out.println(griffindor.getPartyInfo());
        System.out.println(slytherin.getPartyInfo());
    }
}
```

P.D: I'm not a HP fan.

Comment: I will review this when I get home from the market.  For now, here have an answer!

Comment: I pretty much copied your code to experiment with it, and netbeans is giving me errors.  It's telling me that I can't call the methods like setParty and getParty within the Party class, because I am trying to call a non-static method from a static context.

Comment: You first have to create a instance of Party.
Party myParty = new Party(), enemyParty = new Party();

Then you can call myParty.setName("Player party") or myParty.addSpirit(new Spirit(SpiritType.Grokk));


getParty() and setParty() are methods of Spirit.
Non static methods are the ones that work with the state of object instance. That would be object properties like name and party variables. For that to be possible you need a instance of the object, instancing an object means calling the new operator to construct a new copy, having new copies of non static properties.